# How to fix directory traversal vulnerability on Tomcat 9

Tags: apache, tomcat, httpd.conf, directory-traversal

I have a JEE service on a Tomcat 9 container (Debian 10.8). In front of it an Apache Web Server + mod_proxy_ajp.

In my VH I do not have any ProxyPass rule for /manager/html context but if on a Web client I rewrite my URL adding /..;/manager/html (e.g.: https://www.example.org/site/..;/manager/html) the Tomcat Manager asks for crediatials.

Is there a trick to avoid it? Maybe using modsecurity?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just configure the proxy server to reject all paths with a semicolon?  Or even just rewrite them to home

Answer (score 1):

Since [path parameters](https://doriantaylor.com/policy/http-url-path-parameter-syntax) are only used in Tomcat for session tracking (as an alternative to cookies), you can safely remove them in Apache2 from the `..` path segment :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/\.\.;[^/]*(.*)$ $1/..$2 [N]
```

Alternatively you can remove them altogether:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*);[^/]*(.*)$ $1$2 [N]
```

and configure Tomcat to use only cookies for session tracking in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`:

```xml
    <session-config>
        ...
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using a mod_security rules:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@rx ..;/" "phase:1,severity:'CRITICAL',deny,id:129"
```

It works.

Comment: Your regular expression does not catch all possibilities: `/app/..;abc/manager/html` will still be rewritten as `/manager/html` by Tomcat. Try with `/\.\.;[^/]*/`.